# Append data to existing file in Azure Datalake Storage Gen2 Using Rest API

Tags: file, append, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

Rest API available for Azure DataLake Gen2. the documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update#request-body).
Does anyone have examples for the postman or anything like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append is in two stages using this Path - Update API.

You first need to call the action=append to push it to the uncommitted buffer on the server e.g.

```
https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.dfs.core.windows.net/mydata/data/file1?action=append&position=0
```

Remember to pass the mandatory Authorisation, x-ms-version, x-ms-date and Content-Length Headers and the data that you want to append into the body of the request.

Once you have received the 202 Accepted you can then call the action=flush and pass the position that you want the data to be flushed to e.g.

```
https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.dfs.core.windows.net/mydata/data/file1?action=flush&position=13
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know how to use the position parameter properly ? Microsoft's description one really confusing.

Comment: Not an expert on it but the way I got it to work on a new file was to set the flush position to be the length of bytes of the Content-Length from the append call. If you dig up any more information I would be interested to hear it.

Comment: Remember you can also use SAS instead of authorization headers - much less mess (at least for testing purposes).